# Looking to partially fill a fixed size array from file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have to create an array with a fixed size and then fill partially from a data file.  The fixed size needs to be 10 and there are three lines in the file.  With my current code i get seven items in the array listed as ' ' how do I edit this code to just partially fill the array and ignore the empty spots?

```
MAX_COLORS = 10
colors = [''] * MAX_COLORS
counter = int(0)
filename = input("Enter the name of the color file (primary.dat or secondary.dat): ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')
line = infile.readline()
while line != '' and counter < MAX_COLORS:
    colors[counter] = str.rstrip(line)
    counter = counter + 1
    line = infile.readline()
infile.close()
```

Comment: Instead of initialising, use a list then `.append()` every time you read a line instead of just setting.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama would you be able to clarify this any further? Right now when I print what was read my result is ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
colors[counter] = str.rstrip(line)
```

Should be:

```
colors[counter] = line.rstrip()
```

Explanation: Your variable `line` is an object of type `str`, and `rstrip` is a method of `str`.  Calling `line.rstrip()` returns an rstripped copy of `line`.

EDIT:  Based on your comments, I understand now what results you are looking for.  You simply want to read up to 10 lines from the file, or less, and put the values (without newline), into a list.

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your program not just to fix the problems you had, but in addition I cleaned it up and simplified it.  I hope that this code shows you a few other tricks that will be useful to you.

```
MAX_COLORS = 10
colors = []

filename = input("Enter the name of the color file (primary.dat or secondary.dat): ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')

while len(colors) < MAX_COLORS:
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    colors.append(line.rstrip())

infile.close()

print('The colors are:')
for color in colors:
    print('  %s' % color)
```

The issue with this is that if you were to have an extra newline at the end of your file (which can easily happen by accident), that otherwise empty line would be read in as a color.  You probably don't want that.  To solve that problem, you could do it like this:

```
line = infile.readline().rstrip()
if not line:
    break
colors.append(line)
```

This will cause your program to stop reading at the first blank line, or the end of the file, whichever comes first.

Comment: Hello, when I then go to print 'colors' I am still getting seven empty spaces along with the three colors, how do I get it to just print what actually has data in it?

Comment: If you want that, then don't prefill the list.  Just combine my answer with what other people said (use `colors = []`  and then `colors.append(line.rstrip())`

Comment: How did it work out??

Comment: Hello, little_birdie, thanks for checking, that last part was exactly what I was looking for to get the program running correctly, unfortunately it was added in past my due time for the assignment so I missed out.  I really appreciate it though, its amazing how people take so much time answering questions just for fun.  I'm an accountant going for my CPA and I needed a few credit hours to sit for the exam so I took this class for fun.  Its a lot harder than I thought it would be!

Answer (score 1):

As @ LarrytheLlama comments, try to use append:

```
# you do not need str() because rstrip() return str.
colors.append(rstrip(line))
```

Also you might want to remove 'counter' if you do not use it for other purpose.

Comment: Hello, when I try to do that I now get an error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Just updated the answer.